# Questions about melting ice blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have three questions about ice blocks in Minecraft:

1. Do redstone torches melt ice?
2. Which light source melts ice the fastest?
3. Can packed ice melt?

Comment: Please don't ask three questions in one post - ask three separate questions in three different posts instead.

Comment: Sorry it's just that you can't post more than 2 questions a day and their all related

Comment: A wiki is your friend.

Answer (score 8):

1. No.
2. Ice melts if the light source around it is greater than 11. There is no way to speed it up; it either melts or it doesn't. It's completely binary.
3. No.

Sources -

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ice

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_torch

Comment: Can you provide a source with your answer?